# How can I get 208V from this panel?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

Has anyone seen this panel setup before? I just want to get a 208v from the panel, but it 's 250v, two black one white. Any black to white is 125v.

How can I get a 208v from it?

[image]

Comment: Looks like it is a common single/split phase panel, so only 120 volts or 240 volts(125 is a bonus).  If you need 208 volts will need to talk to your power company and change your service.

Comment: The cable hanging down is a big no-no.  Quite sure you can't double up a breaker and quite possible if you think it is grounded you are mistaken, that neutral bus seems isolated from the panel(ground).

Comment: The only way you’ll get 208v is if your service is from 2 phases of a 3-phase electrical supply. Is that what you think you have?

Comment: This might be a you can't get there from here question.  Maybe if you change the question letting us know why you need 208v would be better.  Some machines/devices can handle 240v single or 208v three phase depending on how they are wired.

Comment: You can't get 208V without a transformer. Go shopping.

Comment: You need to fix that situation where you have tiny wires (12 or 14) on a 50A breaker, before you burn your place down.

Comment: OP, you are asking an XY question: asking about *a way to solve a problem* instead of stating what the actual problem is. This tends to lead to frustration.   Please state what you're trying to hook up, and [edit] in a picture of the equipment nameplate that states all the voltage and amperage data. Yes, this panel needs a general Code review starting with the #14s double-tapped onto a 50A breaker. (replace with Siemens Q1515 aka Murray MP1515).  Is there a main breaker elsewhere that shuts off all power here?

Answer (score 8):

Single phase power in the USA/Canada is center-tapped 240V, 120V to grounded center tap.

So, that's a perfectly normal single phase power **sub-**panel for any structure not specifically served by a 208Y 3-phase connection. Ground is via conduit, neutral is isolated from ground, so we know it is a sub-panel.

208V only happens when you have a [3-phase feed](https://www.thermalcorporation.com/208-volts-is-a-weird-voltage-where-did-it-come-from/), and then it has to be of a particular type (if you have access to only 2 phases), or you have to have access to all three phases (not usually the case in a residence.)

If your supply is 240V, the only way you'll get 208V (other than by having the incoming service changed, which is often not an option, or prohibitively expensive) is with a transformer that can take 240V and produce 208V. That's a buck transformer (boost would be the other direction, many can be used either way.) Since you seem to be bodged into a 60A breaker, presumably the transformer would have to be 12,500VA or greater to power your 208V load.

If it's a kiln, just buy new elements, it will be cheaper. But you still need to wire it in correctly, not like this.

As already commented, the cordage kludged in here which we're going to guess is what you are trying to power is a violation in so, so, many ways, some of which might kill you. Neutral is not ground. Bodging cables in so the cover can't be replaced is a violation. Not using strain reliefs is a violation. *Etcetera.*

Comment: I'm OK with the hookup *for testing* as long as the 60A load is switched off. However it needs to be wired in properly as soon as the 208V question is resolved.